# How to XSD-Validating single fields on setting them using moxy

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, moxy

In [this fine post](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html) i learned how to validate xml using moxy. The problem is that the validation comes at last and probably there are many failures due to invalid parameters given to some setter methods.
Is there any way to validate each setter (model based). So that if i set one value this value is validated against its constraints. at the time of each set call - the complete model may be invalidate as hell but i only want validation info about the current set call.
In my case i want to throw IllegalargumentException if someone passes an illegal (by xsd constraint) parameter to one of the setters (all setters are wrapped by an interface).